# Ubuntu black screen with no keyboard screen

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, live-usb

I have been reading other posts regarding the black screen and changing the mode to 'nomodeset' after pressing the shift key when the keyboard comes up on the loasing screen. Only problem is, I don't get that screen when I am loading into the USB. I get the installer boot menu with the options to try ubuntu install etc... How do I get the menu to change the boot settings?